# Python Selenium - Using Try and except in a loop for automated reading on a website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, try-catch

I'm trying to create an automatic soundcloun player. I started learning selenium on python a few days ago, I'm still a beginner.
So I would like to create a loop that works when he enters the page he clicks on "I accept" (For cookies) then presses the space button and refreshes after 60s

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from typing import KeysView
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

driver.implicitly_wait(17)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkk_fNxM_6AhXrgc4BHWcSCjoQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fuser-997915825%2Fpmh-ah-aah&usg=AOvVaw2vFzZHA4d8DH1r5GjZ6e4y")

try:
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')

action = ActionChains(driver)

action.click(on_element = element)

action.perform()

driver.implicitly_wait(33)

except NoSuchElementException:
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()


while True:
   sleep(60)
   driver.refresh()
```

But when I put try: then Except: NoSuchElementException I don't even have time to decompile that I get an error in the lines like :
Try statement must have at least one except or finally clause. Pylance [Ln 17]
Expected expression. Pylance [Ln 28]

I used the right libraries I think:

```
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

And finally when I try to run it I have this nice error : `SyntaxError: expected 'except' or 'finally' block`.

When I remove try and except as follows:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from time import sleep
 from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from typing import KeysView
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

 driver.implicitly_wait(17)

 driver.get("https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkk_fNxM_6AhXrgc4BHWcSCjoQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fuser-997915825%2Fpmh-ah-aah&usg=AOvVaw2vFzZHA4d8DH1r5GjZ6e4y")

 element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')

 action = ActionChains(driver)

 action.click(on_element = element)

 action.perform()

 driver.implicitly_wait(33)

 ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()


 while True:
     sleep(60)
     driver.refresh()
```

He enters the page, he clicks on "I accept" and then he presses the SPACE button to start reading but when he refreshes, since he doesn't have a "cookie acceptance" window anymore, he doesn't even start reading.
that's why I'm looking to use conditions. I've searched several threads about this, I tried to understand their code before copying it but so far all the methods I've tried have failed and it's already been 2 days constantly that it's blocking me, my eyes are starting to hurt.
If anyone can find a solution to my problem, I would be delighted I'll be glad and can find the problem or I'm the problem.

Thanks for your correction, Prophet, here is the new code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from typing import KeysView
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkk_fNxM_6AhXrgc4BHWcSCjoQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fuser-997915825%2Fpmh-ah-aah&usg=AOvVaw2vFzZHA4d8DH1r5GjZ6e4y")

try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')

    action = ActionChains(driver)

    action.click(on_element = element)

    action.perform()

except NoSuchElementException:
  ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()

while True:
    sleep(7)
    driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing indentation.
This is a very basic python syntax rule.
The code inside `try` or `except` or any other block should have indentation relatively to previous code.
With the indentation your code could look like this:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

driver.implicitly_wait(17)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkk_fNxM_6AhXrgc4BHWcSCjoQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fuser-997915825%2Fpmh-ah-aah&usg=AOvVaw2vFzZHA4d8DH1r5GjZ6e4y")

try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')

    action = ActionChains(driver)

    action.click(on_element = element)

    action.perform()

    driver.implicitly_wait(33)

except NoSuchElementException:
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()
```

Also, `driver.implicitly_wait(33)` **is not** a pause command.
`driver.implicitly_wait` is set once per the session. Is sets the timeout, how long time to try finding (pooling) an element on the page.
If you want to make a pause `time.sleep()` should be used, but not recommended since we don't generally recommend to use hardcoded sleeps in Selenium code.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. My code now passes although with some difficulty but that's another matter. By the way for the `driver.implicitly_wait(33)` I was using it because the page load time was taking 5 seconds as the actionchains execute in 250ms I pause the driver for a while to wait for the page to appear. But in this new code I compiled and the two `driver.implicitly_wait` seem useless to me so I removed them here is the new code which passes wonderfully: